# Sound Event Detection and Localization using CRNN

Tags: python, audio, conv-neural-network, microphone, librosa

I trained a model using the [SELD challenges](https://github.com/yinkalario/Two-Stage-Polyphonic-Sound-Event-Detection-and-Localization)
The model train, and I am able to predict and localize sound. But I want to test the feasibility of my model using a [Respeaker microphone array](https://github.com/yinkalario/Two-Stage-Polyphonic-Sound-Event-Detection-and-Localization) to record sound in real-time and use the already developed model to predict the kind of sound and localize the angle.

I have conducted several control experiments using the recorded sound, and the model always predicts wrong values.

**question:**
Is the approach I am taking wrong, or can the model only predict the same sound type it is trained on. Also, any suggestions on how I can conduct the test will be appreciated.

Comment: How is the data used for test different from that used during training?